# Replace a particular string with an escape character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

JavaScript

---

I have a string as follows:

```
#UNICODE#{1f600} #UNICODE#{1f600}
```

and I want to replace each occurrence of '#UNICODE#' with '\u',
so the output should be like

```
\u{1f600} \u{1f600}
```

Tried many different regex in .replace function but no luck.

like

```
('#UNICODE#{1f600} #UNICODE#{1f600}').replace(/#UNICODE#/g,/\u/)
/\u/{1f600}/\u/{1f600}


('#UNICODE#{1f600} #UNICODE#{1f600}').replace(/#UNICODE#/g,\u)
Invalid unicode escape sequence
```

and so on.

Any bright ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove quotes from regex. and add quotes on `\\u`.

Comment: @Tushar, that was just a typo in question, corrected

Comment: This is easy to accomplish with `eval`, but there's gotta be a better way. Problem with `1F600` is that its a surrogate pair, not sure how to decompose that `\u` syntax into two separate `fromCharCode`s, or something similar

Comment: Er, wait, are you looking for the computed string, eg `'\u{1f600}' === ""`, or the literal sequence of a backslash, followed by a u, followed by `{1f600}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `\\u`

```js
let str = '#UNICODE#{1f600} #UNICODE#{1f600}'.replace(/#UNICODE#/g,"\\u")

console.log(str)
str = str.replace(/\\u\{/g,"&#x").replace(/\}/g,";")
console.log(str)
document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = str
```

```html
<span id="x"></span>
```